# 4-bit comparator issue in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, hardware, comparator, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I am new to VHDL and I have an issue writing a 4-bit comparator.
When I want to compare different sets of inputs there is only one output for all of them. And I don't know how to solve this problem. I want to have only one output and need to show 0000 if A is less than B, and 1111 if A is greater than B, and 0011 if they are equal. Can anybody please help me with my problem?

Here is my code:

```vhdl
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity comp_4 is
    port (  A:IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
            B:IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
            output:OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0)
    );
end comp_4;
    
architecture dataflow of comp_4 is
begin
    process
    begin
        if (A=B) then
            output <= "0011";
        elsif (A>B) then
            output <= "1111";
        else
            output <= "0000";
        end if;
        wait;
    end process;
end dataflow;
```

And also my test bench:

```vhdl
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

ENTITY Comparator_test IS
END Comparator_test;

ARCHITECTURE Ctest OF Comparator_test IS
    COMPONENT comp_4 IS
        port(   A:IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
                B:IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
                output:OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;

    SIGNAL a : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
    SIGNAL b : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
    SIGNAL c : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
BEGIN
    uut : comp_4 PORT MAP(a, b , c);
    a <= "0100" , "1111" After 10 NS;
    b <= "0101" , "1100" AFTER 10 NS;
END Ctest;
```

And my simulation looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the inputs on the sensitivity list.

Note, `wait;` stops the process infinitely (only in simulation, it cannot be synthesized).

#### Solution 1:

Use the process' sensitivity list, and remove `wait;`.

```vhdl
architecture dataflow of comp_4 is
begin
    process(A, B)
    begin
        if (A = B) then
            output <= "0011";
        elsif (A > B) then
            output <= "1111";
        else
            output <= "0000";
        end if;
    end process;
end dataflow;
```

#### Solution 2:

Use the sensitivity list of `wait`.

```vhdl
architecture dataflow of comp_4 is
begin
    process
    begin
        if (A = B) then
            output <= "0011";
        elsif (A > B) then
            output <= "1111";
        else
            output <= "0000";
        end if;
        wait on A, B;
    end process;
end dataflow;
```